# Determining hyperbolic or euclidean geometry

Tags: probability-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, information-geometry

Consider the Riemmanian product metric:

$$ ds^2= f(\theta)~d\theta^2 + f(r)~dr^2$$

for $\theta, r>0$ and $f(\theta)=2\sqrt{\theta}K_1(2\sqrt{\theta})$ where $K_1$ is a modified Bessel function.

I obtained this product metric from the Fisher information metric (a tool used in information geometry to obtain a metric from a given distribution function).

I'm wondering about the geometry of this "quarter plane" is. I first suspected that it had hyperbolic geometry but now I am thinking that is has Euclidean geometry based on the form of the metric above.

> Is there a way to tell whether the geometry is hyperbolic or Euclidean via inspection of the metric?

Comment: It should be possible to calculate Christoffel symbols, Riemann, Ricci tensor and scalar curvature. This tool https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/diffgeom.html can be used to do that with symbolic calculation.

Comment: The results should be: non-zero Christoffel symbols: \begin{align}
\Gamma^\theta_{\theta\theta} &= - \frac{K_0\left(2 \sqrt{\theta}\right)}{2 K_1\left(2 \sqrt{\theta}\right) \sqrt{\theta}}\,,&
\Gamma^r_{rr} &= - \frac{K_0\left(2 \sqrt{r}\right)}{2 K_1\left(2 \sqrt{r}\right) \sqrt{r}}\,.
\end{align} Riemann tensor is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let $F(t)$ be an antiderivative of $\sqrt{f(t)}$ then after a change of variables
$$\theta' = F(\theta), \quad r' = F(r)
$$
you get
$$ds^2 = (d \theta')^2 + (dr')^2
$$
and so your metric is locally Euclidean.

Comment: okay so it's locally and globally euclidean, I see

Comment: I myself would be reticent to say that this metric is "globally Euclidean", because I do not know what a "modified Bessel function" is, and so I do not know whether the metric is complete. Without knowing that, I do not know whether this Riemannian manifold is isometric to the entire Euclidean plane, which is what "globally Euclidean" means to me.